# How do I create an unbox instance of an ADT?

Tags: haskell, unboxing, algebraic-data-types

I'm having trouble finding good resources that work for how to make my data types unboxed, for use in an unboxed vector. How would I make the data type

```
data Color = Yellow | Red | Green | Blue | Empty deriving (Show, Eq)
```

be an instance of Unbox?

Edit: after poking around a bit more, it seems that by forcing paramaters in some functions to be strict, I can convince GHC to unbox them automatically. If this applicable in my case? How do I know which paramaters to make strict?

Comment: Have you looked at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10866718)?

Comment: Yes, GHCi told me `Vector`, `MVector`, and `U.Unbox` are not derivable classes. Not to mention I don't really understand what is going on there, especially with the `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` thing, and I'd like to understand things before I use them.

Comment: Not that it answers your question, but have you tried working with boxed vectors here?  They'll handle your data type without hassle.

Comment: Of course. Extrating the values from the vector is still taking up about 12% of the time in my program though, and unboxing the vector seems like the way to reduce that.

Comment: A simple workaround is to use integers wrapped into a newtype (like `newtype Color = Color Int`) instead of an enumerated data type. And then add helper functions for constructing/deconstructing instances. It's not very nice, but if performances is important, it could help. See [Performance-Data types-Enumerations](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Performance/Data_types#Enumerations).

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [vector-th-unbox](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector-th-unbox/latest/doc/html/Data-Vector-Unboxed-Deriving.html) package to derive the instance for you. You just need to provide conversion functions to and from some existing `Unbox` type:

```
colorToWord8 :: Color -> Word8
colorToWord8 = ...

word8ToColor :: Word8 -> Color
word8ToColor = ...

derivingUnbox "Color"
  [t| Color -> Word8 |]
  colorToWord8
  word8ToColor
```

Answer (score 0):

`GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` won't help you here because you're dealing with a 'full-blown' ADT, rather than a newtype wrapping something that's already an instance of `Unbox`.

Your data type is more suited to boxed vectors.  Use `Data.Vector.Unboxed` if you need to hold more primitive numeric types like `Double`s, `Int`s, etc.  Perhaps you can make `Color` an instance of `Unbox`, but it almost certainly isn't worth [the hassle](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.10.0.1/doc/html/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html).  Import `Data.Vector` and you'll be set:

```
import qualified Data.Vector as V

Color = Red | Blue deriving Show

someColors :: V.Vector Color
someColors = V.fromList [Red, Blue, Blue, Red]
```

Comment: As I mentioned in a previous comment, getting data out of my regular boxed vector was taking up 12% of the time in my program. I'd like to eliminate some of that by switching to unboxed.